# Access Alfresco Workflows I've started in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, workflow, task, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to create a report about the workflows (Adhoc task) that a person is/was involved in and I'm having trouble with accessing the workflows that the person has started and are currently in progress.

I am using JavaScript API and using `workflow` Root Scope object. With this I can access only finished task by using `workflow.getCompletedTasks();` however, I need to get the tasks that are also in progress.

Any solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Does [workflow.getAssignedTasks()](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-WorkflowManager.html) not give you all the workflows assigned to the current user? And if so, is that not what you need?

Comment: Actually, no. Because with workflow.getAssignedTasks() you get all tasks that other user assigned to you.
i.e. Someone else started a workflow and assigned you as a asignee.

I need to get the workflow that I started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to drill in to the repository web scripts that do this to see how they work. For example, look at this:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/workflow-instances?initiator=admin&exclude=jbpm$wcmwf:*,jbpm$wf:articleapproval,activiti$publishWebContent,jbpm$publishWebContent,jbpm$inwf:invitation-nominated,jbpm$imwf:invitation-moderated,activiti$activitiInvitationModerated,activiti$activitiInvitationNominated&skipCount=0&maxItems=50&pooledTasks=false&state=COMPLETED
```

That's what the "Workflows I've Started" panel calls. But you can change the state argument to ACTIVE and you'll get the in-flight workflows.

Maybe you can use that web script as-is to meet your needs. If not, you can crack it open and create your own to do whatever you want.